# Data Validation based on presence of text in three adjacent cells

Tags: excel, validation, if-statement, formula, offset

I am trying to find a way to data validate without using macros (not allowed at work). We need to validate a cell based on the presence (or lack of) text in three adjacent cells. So:

```
IF A1 contains text, AND B1 contains text, AND C1 contains text THEN
D1 has to be greater than Zero
```

If any of those queries are false (i.e A1, B1, or C1 does not contain text) then Cell D1 is locked.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I understand your algorithm as "if (condition) then *D1 has to be greater than Zero* else *D1 is locked*": what does that mean? And what are asking exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with data validation:

Select column D then under the data tab -> data tools -> data validation -> select "Custom" and enter the following data validation formula:

```
=(OFFSET(D1,0,-3,1,1)<>"")*(OFFSET(D1,0,-2,1,1)<>"")*(OFFSET(D1,0,-1,1,1)<>"")*(D1>0)
```

[image]

This will check to see if the adjacent 3 cells to the left of each cell in column D are not empty and to make sure that the cell in column D is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
=AND(A1<>"",B1<>"",C1<>"",VALUE(D1)>0)
```